# Calculating areas vs volumes in multivariable calculus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, volume

The formula for the area is:
$$\iint_RdA$$

The formula for the volume is:
$$\iint _R (f(x,y)-g(x,y))\,dA$$

In other words, the volume is surface base's area * height, or the base repeated over and over throughout a certain height, if I understand this correctly. Which I think implies that solids have to be decomposed in cubic/parallelepiped/cylindrical like shapes.

What's confusing me is that in the formula for the area is that it can be rewritten as:
$$\iint_RdA = \iint_R (1-0)\,dA$$

in other words, a solid with 1 of height. Which means it's giving a volume, not an area. What am I getting wrong here? I also don't see where the Riemann-like approximation with the parallelepipeds fits in this.

Comment: It's because the parallel piped picture is not necessary. Another way to think of integration is "collecting" little pieces of density times area. If your density is $1$, you retrieve the area. This is also described by Riemann sums, but interpreting the density as some height is not necessary because the function and its graph are two separate objects.

Comment: We can interpret volume as being a triple integral, $V = \iiint dV$. But if you happen to want the volume between $z=f(x,y)$ and $z=g(x,y)$ we can do the $z$ integral first to get $$V = \iint \int_{g(x,y)}^{f(x,y)} dz \: dA = \iint f(x,y) - g(x,y) \: dA$$

Comment: @NinadMunshi I think I understand. Thank you!